# Selector type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, selector, rx-swift

I'm trying to get ARSessionDelegate method using selector, but im getting this error:
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

There is mine code:

```
#selector(ARSessionDelegate.session(_:didUpdate:) as ((ARSessionDelegate) -> (ARSession, ARFrame) -> Void))
```

That's how this method looks like:

```
public protocol ARSessionDelegate : ARSessionObserver {
    optional func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame)
}
```

And also, I am trying to make an rx extension for the ARKit session using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51816144/how-to-convert-delegate-to-observable-rxswift) answer, but im not sure it's caused the problem.

Comment: May be it needs to be `@objc` if it used in #selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are multiple methods with the same selector name, you are forced to implement the method in the delegate and forward the calls using a subject. Like this:

```
extension ARSession: HasDelegate { }

extension Reactive where Base: ARSession {
    var delegate: ARSessionDelegateProxy {
        return ARSessionDelegateProxy.proxy(for: base)
    }

    var didUpdate: Observable<ARFrame> {
        return delegate.didUpdate.asObservable()
    }
}

final class ARSessionDelegateProxy
: DelegateProxy<ARSession, ARSessionDelegate>
, DelegateProxyType
, ARSessionDelegate {
    init(parentObject: ARSession) {
        super.init(
            parentObject: parentObject,
            delegateProxy: ARSessionDelegateProxy.self
        )
    }

    deinit {
        didUpdate.onCompleted()
    }

    public static func registerKnownImplementations() {
        self.register { ARSessionDelegateProxy(parentObject: $0) }
    }

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
        didUpdate.onNext(frame)
    }

    fileprivate let didUpdate = PublishSubject<ARFrame>()
}
```